# Views arguments from URL

Tags: views, webforms

how to get the arguments from the URL and store it for further processing in views drupal 7.I am passing a token from a webform to a view through custom redirect URL.Later i need that value for some calculations.I need some help on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the environment you want to use your parameters into. If in code, URL arguments are always available through [arg($x)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7), with `$x` being the zero based position of the argument in the URL.

If the context is Views, then bobmct's answer seems relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for Drupal 6.

In Views 2, I've had to define where in the URL the parameter(s) would be located positionally (e.g. blah/view_name/%/%) where the % represent parameters 1 and 2 respectively; then, in my next view (which was either another display or attached view within the same view file) I defined the arguments in the argument section and then they could be referenced as %1, or %2 respectively.